# How to quote a list?

Tags: lists, citing, enumerate, quoting

I want to quote a list in the following way:

> We haven't produced an original list. But another group made this list: [1]
>
> "1. bla
>
> "2. bla bla
>
> "3. bla bla bla"

Is there a simple way to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Do you want to put a citation mark before the list?

Comment: @Astrinus I want it to render just like in my question, with a quotation mark before every bullet point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=``\arabic*., ref=\arabic*]
    \item bal
    \item bla blala bla
    \item bla bla bla''
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`ref=\arabic*` is needed so that if you label an item and `\ref` it later, you won't get `"` in the reference.

Comment: Beaten me also!

Comment: @Astrinus Oh No! :-)

Comment: Don't worry, your answers are often more detailed and usually better than mine, so it is a good thing!