# Quoting a Numbered List

Tags: lists, enumerate

Related: [How to quote a list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226839/how-to-quote-a-list)

I am trying to quote a list like so:

```
"1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3"
```

I want the first list item to have the quote before it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3"
 \end{enumerate}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine the label of the first item like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item["\refstepcounter{enumi}\labelenumi] Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3"
 \end{enumerate}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image]