# How to quote enumerations?

Tags: citing, lists, enumerate

Let's say I have the following enumerate list, how do I go about quoting the list?

```latex
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Text1
    \item Text2
    \item Text3
    \item Text4
    \item Text5
\end{enumerate}
```

[How to quote a list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226839/how-to-quote-a-list) is a similar question, however the answer was based on the input of the op.

Overall, I am not really sure what approach should I take as I have seen a couple answers here that differs from each other.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What do you mean "input of the op"?  From what I can see, that question is identical to what you are asking, since you (the OP) are also inputting the enumeration.

Comment: The answer is based on his specific formatting specified in the question statement, whereas my question is more towards what is the correct way of quoting a list. I guess 
I could have clarified the question a bit more.

Comment: If your question is one of *style*, it may considered opinion-based and/or not TeX related.  It would definitely be better if you had a quote style in mind and wanted to know how to implement it.

Comment: What do you mean by "quoting the list" ? Something like `\beqin{quote} \begin{enumerate} ... \end{quote}` or something completely different?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thinking about it you might be right that my question seems like an opinion one. I guess lacking a guideline for quoting lists on my end also does not really help with my case.

Comment: @PeterWilson I am aware of that one but would it not be considered plagiarism given that I am not presenting the list in literal quotes?

Comment: @GoksenU.Guler No plagarism. The `quote` environment puts the text into a narrower environment but does not add any quotation marks. Try it.